# Expanding a Pandas.dataframe after encoding

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My actual problem need to encode strings in a data frame, as I do in the following step:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"cool": list("ABC"), "not_cool": list("CBA")})
encoding = {"A": [0, 0, 1], "B": [0, 1, 0], "C": [1, 0, 0]}
```

Which is encoded:

```
df.applymap(encoding.get)
```

Now, what I have is a data frame where the elements are lists:

```
cool       not_cool
[0, 0, 1]  [1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]  [0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 1]
```

I need to expand this as matrix. How to do that? My first thought was iterate through the rows and apply numpy.hstack for joining, store it and numpy.vstack the stored rows, but it doesn't work as intended. 
Other way is to this data frame to create a new one, where every column will be the n-th element of the lists. If I had this data frame, the pandas.DataFrame.values would get what I need:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6  # Column names
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick answer:

```
x = df.applymap(encoding.get)
(x.cool+x.not_cool).values  # gives you matrix without the headers
# should be elementary to get labels you need in there
```

This adds the two columns together (adding lists actually concatenates them).   The values just get the array of lists.

Updating for @mithrado comment

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((x.cool+x.not_cool).values), columns=range(6))]
# will give you a dataframe with the required values
```

You seem to ask fro the columns as a another row in the DataFrame?   Why would you want it that way?

Comment: It is always helpful if you explain your answer in more detail: What does it do, how does it help with the problem and how should it be implemented in a sumewhat larger context?

Comment: This does not solve the problem, since the final object still a series of lists. It can be solved with `np.vstack([a for a in x.cool+x.not_cool])` I would like to hear more people, thou.

Comment: added the comment and took to a data frame as well @mithrado

Comment: this does the magic: `X = df.applymap(encoding.get)`
`X = np.vstack(X.sum(axis=1))`